# Яким може бути походження прізвища Бойправ?

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Вже дуже давно цим цікавлюсь, але нічого не можу знайти. Часто дають англійський жартівливий варіант ("хлопці завжди праві" і т.ін.), "правий бій", якісь версії про французьке походження після війни 1812 року від одного з носіїв прізвища.

Прізвище нестандартне для слов'янських мов, на мою думку. Якщо довго шукати Гуглом у Гугл Книгах чи навіть по всьому Інтернету, можна побачити, що прізвище поширене у Чернігівській області. Всі мої родичі з цим прізвищем з Козелецького району (Сорокошичі, Косачівка, Лошакова Гута...). Часто воно чомусь виринає в Ніжині. Мені здається, що воно все ж іншомовного походження, але не зрозуміло, якого ж саме.

Можливо, хтось знає? Чи має якісь версії?

Доповнення від 22 листопада 2017 р.: Отримав версію, що це може бути від слов'янського Боєправ. Версія сумнівна, Боєправи є, але вони якраз з'являються пізніше і переважно в містах і здаються мені пізнішими переробками прізвища Бойправ.

Доповнення від 13 червня 2019 р.: Поширення прізвища можна досить чітко побачити на [https://ridni.org/karta/бойправ](https://ridni.org/karta/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2)
Там є також і розділ "Походження прізвища БОЙПРАВ", але текст цього розділу насправді з книги Павла Чучка "Слов'янськi особовi iмена украïнцiв: iсторико-етимологiчний словник" і стосується імені Бой, а не прізвища Бойправ. Прізвище Бойправ в тексті навіть не згадується: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=M-sHKtbjF2EC&pg=PA70 Вважаю, що ця інформація не стосується походження прізвища Бойправ.

Comment: Це може бути цілком українське прізвисько для людини, що часто говорила «бо й правʼ…» («бо й правда», і далі висловлювання) на рівні слова-паразита. (Версія з голови під впливом подібного походженя прізвища Напримеров).

Answer (score 1):

Ну, здається, не лише ви шукаєте походження прізвища Бойправ, а й люди на [цьому](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2) форумі (а також тут згадується село Сорокошичі). Згідно до інформація там - прізвище Бойправ походить від тако самого прізвизька, яке, напевно, мав якийсь сміливий та чесний воїн ("бой" - "бій", "правивй" - "справедливий"), або ж людина, яка вміло та справделиво могла владнати місцеві конфлікти.

На цьому формуі також припустили, що прізвище є скороченням від якогось прізвиська (однак, тут зауважують, що воно складалося із двох слів). А також згідно до даних у цьому архіві (він, звичайно, неповний, однак можна побачити співвідношення) найбільше людей із таким прізвищем справді із Чернігівської області.

Також згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0), можу сказати, що прізвище це (саме на території Чернігівщини) зустрічалося ще в 1782р:

> У 1782 р. у Старо-Карпилівській Гуті Києво-Братського монастиря
> проживали 58 чоловіків і 48 жінок… Посполиті мали прізвища Діброва,
> **Акуліна Бойправ**, 90-річний Дем'ян Лошак (мав 5 синів), Дяченко, Прохор
> Скопець, Мазаненко…

Це всі матеріали, які є в Інтернеті... Тобто можна точно сказати, що прізвище справді старе і навіть є теорія його походження, однак вона не точна, хоча, на мою думку, має право на існування.

А також, на рахунок іноземного походження, бачив припущення, що це може бути єврейське прізвище, однак ніяких вагомих доказів у джерелі не було.

Comment: О,так, деякі з цих посилань результати моїх пошуків у мережі ("єврейське прізвище", наприклад)=) 
Всі ці теорії походження прізвища звичайно мають право на існування, але, на мою думку, не мають жодного відношення до власне походження цього прізвища. Хоча сумнів завжди є, звичайно.

Comment: @SergyOrloff, так сумніви є і, на жаль, спростувати чи довести цю теорію буде складно. Можливо у вас є ще якісь матеріали окрім тих, що наведені у запитанні?

Comment: Я додав дещо 13-го червня. Є ще деякі моменти - наприклад, мені здається, що французька версія походження можливо пішла від дружини Василя Марковича, яку звали Антуанетта Францівна де Олів. Але вона там (а саме в Сорокошичах) з'явилася лише у 1847 році, а прізвище з'явилося раніше. А можливо це і не пов'язано... 
Треба якось знайти час і поїздити по архівам, можливо там щось вдасться локалізувати, чи знайти інший варіант написання.